# Microsoft Graph - POST request error 20132

Tags: php, rest, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-edu

I can't seem to get a POST request to create assignments using Microsoft Graph.

Both in the Graph Explorer and in PHP I get the same error: `"message": "The content of the request is invalid. Common causes are an invalid Content-Type header or no content in the body.",`

Endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/education/classes/class-id/assignments

Request Headers: `content-type: application/json`

Body:

```
{
  "dueDateTime": "2014-02-01T00:00:00Z",
  "displayName": "Midterm 1",
    "instructions":  {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "Read chapters 1 through 3"
    },
      "grading": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.education.assignments.api.educationAssignmentPointsGradeType",
        "maxPoints": 100
      },
      "assignTo": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.education.assignments.api.educationAssignmentClassRecipient"
      },
      "status":"draft",
      "allowStudentsToAddResourcesToSubmission": true
}
```

Any help would be truly appreciated!

Please see image of Graph Explorer below.

[image: Microsoft Graph Example Request]

Comment: Could you please provide the screen shoot of the request in the MS Graph Explore?

Comment: Hi @kikang sure, please see image above. This is one of the examples I've tried. Under 'Request Headers' I have Content-type: application/json set.

Comment: Figured it out. Removing the "contentType": "Text", attribute from the instructions worked.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Removing the `"contentType": "Text"` attribute from instructions worked.